# Working with Nested Lists in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list A = [1,2,3,[4,5,[6,7,8]]]
I want to convert A into a list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]. How can I do this?
There is a restriction that i don't have to hardcode it.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Exact dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395/2988730. The name of the operation you are looking for is "flatten".